# How to support apple sign in with aws cognito?

Tags: ios, amazon-cognito, apple-sign-in

apple will start requiring support for apple sign in this 2020.

How do you use it with aws cognito?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean, as mentioned in this article?: https://aws.amazon.com/tr/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-sign-in-with-apple-for-amazon-cognito/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign in with Apple is already supported, you can check the below link:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-cognito-identity-pools-now-supports-sign-in-with-apple/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-sign-in-with-apple-for-amazon-cognito/

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Note that there is no Cognito identity pool support. So it is not accurate to say Cognito supports Sign in with Apple, because a primary use case is to map the external IdP to an authorizable identity.   I'd like to hear how folks are working around this limitation for when a set of IdPs such as Google, Facebook are being used.

Comment: now they do support: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-cognito-identity-pools-now-supports-sign-in-with-apple/

Comment: We are trying to set up SIWA on AWS and are struggling with automatic sign outs after 10 min. As Apples Tokens are only valid 10 min. Do you experience the same issue? More details: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/2513

Comment: Please note if u use hosted UI and redirects to Safari or WebView then apple will not approve your app. Apple looks for a smooth user experience with touchid and face detection rather than making users enter password at a browser